# Symfony send email with Swift Mailer and o2switch

Tags: php, symfony, email, ssl

I have an email account from http://www.o2switch.fr/, I can get informations for configure SMTP in my panel and I get that :

```
For TLS/SSL :

Username : myemail@mydomain.fr
Password : mypassword
Host : xxxxxx.o2switch.net, Port SMTP : 465

And without SSL

Username : myemail@mydomain.fr
Password : mypassword
Host : mail.mydomain.fr, Port SMTP : 26
```

So now in Symfony, I'm trying to configure and send email with Swift Mailer but I have no error, and I don't receive any mail.

This is what I have (with SSL for example) :

in parameters.yml :

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: xxxxxx.o2switch.net
mailer_user: myemail@mydomain.fr
mailer_password: mypassword
auth_mod: login
encryption: ssl
```

in my script :

```
    $from = 'myemail@mydomain.fr';

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Subject')
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->setTo('another_gmail_address')                        
    ->setBody('My body HTML);
```

But this has no effect. (With SSL configuration, or not).

If I tried with `mail()` from PHP, it's ok, I receive an email.
The same if I change parameters.yml for use gmail smtp, it's ok I receive an email.

What can I do ? Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

I can tell anything about o2switch.net   but i had simillar problem ,

soluton was to spool emails and send them from command line (in cron) 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html